# More explicit indexing

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[10, 11], [12, 13]])
idx = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
print(x[idx[0], idx[1]])
```

It outputs `tensor([11, 13, 10])` and it's correct but is there a way to make the last row more explicit? I want something like `x[*idx]` because my tensor has many dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```py
print(x[idx.tolist()])
```